# HashSet to List conversion

Tags: c#, hashset

works with list: `return Alf.CBytes.Find(x => x.name.Contains(a));`

doesn't work with hashset: `return Alf.CBytes.Contains(x => x.name.Contains(a));`

How could I make it work with a hashset?

Comment: Some working code to reproduce the issue would be useful.

Comment: Did you notice `Find` returns an element, whereas `Contains` returns a boolean?

Comment: Also, please provide definition of "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements you provided are doing different things, so I will act as if you only provided the second statement.

Using `Any` you will get the same behavior as `Contains` (Which is what you would use in your list also, because `Find` has other purposes)

```
return Alf.CBytes.Any(x => x.name.Contains(a));
```

Edit: to get the item:

```
return Alf.CBytes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name.Contains(a)); // return null if not found
return Alf.CBytes.First(x => x.name.Contains(a)); // throw exception if not found
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool'

Comment: @DarkDeSaint Are you trying to get an item or determine if it exists?

Comment: I need to get the item

Comment: @DarkDeSaint Edited, please make sure you are more clear with your questions.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was searching for